# Como usar substrings en c# dentro de un CSV?

Tags: c#

Buenas como andan? estoy con algo que me esta quemando la cabeza, necesito leer los datos de un csv y despues mediante substrings (se me ocurre) almacenar cada columna del csv. Ejemplo:

Fecha:     Sucursal:  Cod-Articulo(etc..)

10062019        6       4312

10062019        6       4312

10062019     6       4312

10062019     6       4312

10062019     6       4312

Necesitaria hacer un substring para cada Fecha, uno para cada sucursal, y otro para el codigo de articulo. Eso pero para cada fila.. actualmente si lo paso como esta ahora Fecha por ejemplo no me trae todo lo que esta en [0]. Y despues esos substrings insertarlo en una tabla.

¿Que intente?

Bueno mediante un vector almacene todas las lineas de todos los CSV son 7, pero se cargan periodicamente asi que es ilimitado.

```
//Selecciono los archivos que son como "open25"

                    string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Proyecto SFTP - 
                    SQL-Pedidos_Poti\LOCAL_DOWNLOAD\", "Open25*");

                    //Console.WriteLine("cantidad de archivos que empiezan 
                     con Open25 son:... {0}.", dirs.Length);

                    foreach (string dir in dirs)
                    {

                        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dir);
                        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            string line = sr.ReadLine();

                            string[] values = line.Split('|');

                            Fecha_Stock = values[0];
                            Sucursal = values[1];
                            Cod_Art = values[2];
                            Ean = values[3];
                            Stock_Actual = values[4];
                            Art_En_Promocion = values[5];
                            Fecha_Inicio_Promo = values[6];
                            Fecha_Fin_Promo = values[7];


                            foreach (string item in values)
                            {

                              Console.WriteLine(item);


                            }
```

**EDIT** Ahora si funciona lo que queria gracias a la ayuda de Leandro, ahora necesito insertarlo en una tabla, estaba usando el cmd.parameters.add pero no me funciono así que estoy usando esto:

```
foreach (var items in lista_stock)
                    {

 Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7}", 
 items.Fecha_Stock, items.Sucursal, items.Cod_Art, items.Ean, 
 items.Stock_Actual, items.Art_En_Promocion, items.Fecha_Ini_Promo, 
 items.Fecha_Fin_Promo);


                        dbconnect.Update("INSERT INTO [T001_IMPORTAR_STOCK] 
 (Fecha_Stock, Sucursal, Cod_Articulo, EAN , Stock_Actual , 
 Art_En_Promocion, Fecha_Ini_Promo, Fecha_Fin_Promo) VALUES('" +  
 items.Fecha_Stock  + "','" + items.Sucursal + "','" + items.Cod_Art + "','" 
 + items.Ean + "', '" + items.Stock_Actual+ "' , '" + 
  items.Art_En_Promocion+ "' , '" + items.Fecha_Ini_Promo+ "' , '" 
 +items.Fecha_Fin_Promo+"',)");



                        }
```

Pero no me inserta, puse un stop con este codigo y todo parece ir bien.. el console.writeline arriba me sigue trayendo todo.

**PD:** Pido mil disculpas por usar respuesta cuando deberia editar, soy medio newbie y pense que iba a citar a Leandro.

**EDIT 2**

Nuevo metodo de insercion, le puse un stop pero no para en la linea del executenonquery.. se me hace raro.

[image]

Comment: No termino de entender donde tenes el problema.. ya hiciste el split.. entonces en donde esta tu problema?

Comment: Necesito obtener todas las fechas. Ademas de que tengo dividir los substrings, así como esta ahora me trae todo en el "Console.WriteLine(item)" necesito dividirlo por fecha, sucursal, etc. Y necesito que traiga todo.. lo que hace ahora es traerme todo pero por la ultima fecha.. no todas.

Comment: eh.. no entiendo.. todo lo que pedis, esta en tu codigo! antes del foreach, cada variable tiene lo que vos queres. si imprims cada variable, vas a ver que el contenido es lo que queres.. el foreach no sirve para nada ahi, porque cada valor ya lo separaste...

Comment: Imprimi la variable y lo que se imprime me da todo repetido :(. Por ejemplo le asigne a Cod_Art = Values [3] (creo) y lo unico que me devuelve es "4870" cuando deberian ser varias entradas.. pero bueno, tal vez redacte mal la pregunta y no se entiende :( perdón.

Comment: En el ejemplo de archivo que muestras no hay ningun 4870, solo veo un 4312. Ademas porque usas el `|` en el split cuando el caracter no separa nada en la linea?

Comment: y en line hay siempre cosas distintas? yo sigo sin terminar de comprender por donde viene tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tienes lineas de varios archivos no se usa ningun vector debes usar clases y listas, entonces defines:

```
public class xxClass
{
    public string Fecha_Stock {get;set;}
    public string Sucursal {get;set;}
    public string Cod_Art {get;set;}
    public string Ean {get;set;}

    //otras propiedades
}
```

Por supuesto puedes poner un mejor nombre a la class

Para despues usarlos de esta forma

```
List<xxClass> listaDatos = new List<xxClass>();

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Proyecto SFTP - SQL-Pedidos_Poti\LOCAL_DOWNLOAD\", "Open25*");

foreach (string file in files)
{

    string lineas = File.ReadAllLines(file);

    foreach(string line in lineas)
    {
        string[] values = line.Split(' ');

        xxClass item = new xxClass();
        item.Fecha_Stock = values[0];
        item.Sucursal = values[1];
        item.Cod_Art = values[2];
        item.Ean = values[3];
        //demas datos

        listaDatos.Add(item);
    }
}

//se lista los datos
//
foreach(var item in listaDatos)
{
    Consola.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} ...", item.Fecha_Stock, 
                            item.Sucursal, 
                            item.Cod_Art, 
                            item.Ean, ...); //completas propiedades
}
```

Creas una lista del tipo de la class y vas agregando instancias con el `Add()`

En este caso por el ejemplo que has puesto use el `espacio` como separador de cada dato

Comment: Buenisimo, me sirvió, ahora quedaria hacer el INSERT que en mi edicion del tema te comenté.

Comment: no se que haces dentro de `dbconnect.Update()` pero no se concatenan NUNCA los valores en un string, tienes que usar parametros

Comment: Si lo se.. pero cuando utilice cmd.parameters.add("@nomparam", tipodedato).value = items.Fecha_Stock por ejemplo así con todos.. solo me traia los primeros 10 elementos de la lista en la consola y tampoco insertaba

Comment: Si inspeccionas la lista  de items cuantos observas? son solo 10 o hay mas que no se iteran. cuando dices que no insertaba es porque obtienes algun error? porque si es asi el problema no esta en el uso de parametros, sino en que algun valor no se esta asignando correctamente, pero seria un analisis diferente al de esta consulta. Igual esto que planteas no es excusa para dejar de usar parametros.

Comment: Si yo traigo todos los items me trae todas las lineas de todos los csv, eso funciona correctamente. Cuando ejecuto la aplicación no me tira ningun error, solo reviso la tabla y veo que no inserta. Si lo se, cuando pueda lo modifico.

Comment: No ejecutes la aplicacion, pon breakpoint en el codigo para poder ir viendo por donde pasa la ejecucion, quizas piensas que esta ejecutando el insert pero en realida dno lo hace, eso de revisar la tabla no aporta nada sino compruebas que la operacion se realzia en el codigo, cuando desarrollas debe poder depurar paso a paso inspeccionando que sucede

Comment: Claro, igual lo probe.. me olvide contarte.. puse un stop en el dbconnect.update y lo que hace en el console.WriteLine es traerme todo por fila: Te lo muestro:  12062019 6 1234 1323434 30 0 10101970 10101970 y cuando le doy a continuar me trae otra fila y asi..

Comment: el traer todo por fila esta bien en el Console.WriteLine() pero para el dbconnect.update() no aplica, tienes que usar parametros. Ademas si pones un stop no necesitas el Console.WriteLine, porque puede pasar el mouse sirecto sobre las variables he inspeccionarlas

Comment: Ahi lo edite, pero directamente ignora el stop, que raro..

Comment: Ya funciona !!!! Al final rompia por los tipos de datos, asi que parsee los datetimes y ya estaria ok.. el tema es que hace el proceso todo el tiempo, hay alguna forma de decir que no haga mas la consulta hasta que llegue a la fina final, no se si hacer un for dentro de un foreach o de alguna otra forma :(

Comment: no entiendo porque tienes un for dentro de un foreach, ademas las consultas las harias luego de volcar todos los datos de los archivos a la lista

Comment: Nono, lo del for dentro del foreach lo pense para marcarle un limite a la consulta.. es que tambien hay otro problema. Espero que me entiendas pero esta aplicación no la desarrolle yo, yo la agarre y tengo que hacerla funcionar, pero esta bastante mal hecha..

Comment: Basicamente la aplicación tiene un timer que ejecuta toda la aplicación cada 15 segundos y es por eso que el foreach se ejecuta nuevamente creo, entendes? es complejo, pero gracias de todas formas por tu ayuda !